# apply multiple selected true to option jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="testd" name="testd[]" multiple="" style="min-height: 100px;">
    <option value="16">test1</option>
    <option value="21">test2</option>
    <option value="27">test3</option>
    <option value="24">test4</option>
</select>
```

how to apply seleted true to multiple option , 
example 16,24 , want to apply seleted true to option

i tried

```
var optionsToSelect = ['16,24'];
              var select = document.getElementById( 'testd' );

              for ( var i = 0, l = select.options.length, o; i < l; i++ )
              {
                o = select.options[i];
                console.log(o);
                if ( optionsToSelect.indexOf( o.value ) != -1 )
                {
                  o.selected = true;
                }
              }
```

not working perfectly , it will selects all the four options

Comment: As you have tagged your question with jQuery. Simple `$("#testd").val(['16','24']);` will do the job for you. Just note: tag your questions properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
var optionsToSelect = ['16,24'];
```

to

```
var optionsToSelect = ['16','24'];
```

This is how to define an array of strings. Else your code works fine.

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/kafuvoko/1/edit)**

Comment: Simple `$("#testd").val(['16','24']);` will do. I have modified @Alek example for demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/whlkE

Comment: @Satpal , that looks great, but i think OP is not using jQuery, though the tag exists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `optionsToSelect` is not proper, you need to store the different ids in separate indexes in the array

Since you are using jQuery try

```
var optionsToSelect = [16, 24];
$('#testd option').filter(function () {
    return $.indexOf(+this.value, optionsToSelect) >= 0
}).prop('selected', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selValues="16,24";
$.each(selValues.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#testd option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

[example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AKdGI)